# Web browser Service Worker contributing to DDoS attacks and spam?

Tags: ddos, botnet, service-worker

Google and CloudFlare have recently indicated that my home IP address is contributing to a DDoS or spam network.

In addition to all the other usual vectors, are web browser Service Workers a potential concern? It appears that Service Workers are intermittent background threads in the browser, and can run when their websites are not being browsed.

Could a buggy Service Worker potentially contribute to a DDoS of its own source website, no malicious behavior intended?